# How do I make this object exist within sessions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Here's the deal: I have a site where multiple people will be sharing the same account and should each be able to be on a page that uploads files and keeps a list of the files they've uploaded that session. The controller for the file uploading page looks like

```
public class FileUploadController : Controller
{

   // ...

    private List<ThreePartKey> uploadedFiles = new List<ThreePartKey> ();

    public ActionResult Index ( )

    {
          // ...
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index (HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
         // ...

        if (!errorOccured)
        {
            uploadedFiles.Add(new ThreePartKey { orgname = selectedOrgName, catname = selectedCatName, filename = fileNameNoExtension, fullfilepath = newFileUrlPathAndName });
        }

        // ...
   }
```

and the problem is that `uploadedFiles` keeps getting re-initialized whenever         `[HttpPost] public ActionResult Index (HttpPostedFileBase file)` is called, meaning the user's list of uploaded files only shows the last uploaded one. So I instead tried

```
private static List<ThreePartKey> uploadedFiles = new List<ThreePartKey> ();
```

and that screwed up everything because all the signed-in users are sharing the same list.

Is there any easy way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: If multiple people are sharing the same account, then your best option is going to be cookies. But if you make people sign into a unique account when they download, then go with a database storage option.

Answer (score 2):

`Controller`s are instantiated and destroyed on every request. If you want to persist information in a webserver it is strongly advised to use a permanent backing store such as a database.

You can use `static` state in ASP.NET applications (WebForms, MVC, OWIN, etc) however this is only recommended for caching for performance. It cannot be relied upon because `static` state is only local to the current `AppDomain` in the current Application Pool (`w3wp.exe` instance) - if your website is run in multiple pools or appdomains, or if your application is restarted (or killed due to inactivity) then the stored state is lost.

Comment: AND if you are in a web farm/cluster then the "static" variable is NOT transferred across to other servers in the cluster either.

Answer (score 0):

On option is to provide a 'session' code/id with each request.  When user first connects to your site, they are given a session-code (I use 'code' to indicate it has nothing to do with what we would normally call 'session').

Every link has that session-code as part of the url and every post includes the session-code.  Then your upload cache can be:

```
private static ILookup<int, ThreePartKey> uploadedFiles;
```

(or dictionary if you prefer)

```
private static IDictionary<int, IList<ThreePartKey>> uploadedFiles;
```

Depends on the size of the rest of your site if this is workable or not - in most cases probably not as described... but could be managed, eg use the IP address as the 'code' or if you're using AnglurJS or single page application.

As pointed out, any static/singleton cache will still be lost if the app pool is reset, eg via the inactivity timeout setting in IIS.

Another option is to persist the files in subfolders based on the user's IP address.

You've only stipulated that they all use the same login, not how the files are stored etc, so maybe this would work for you.